# The Certificate Authority Service is installed on this computer

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012-r2

I'm trying to add my windows server 2012 to a domain but the "Change" button in the "computer Name" tab of the "System Properties" is disabled with a note:

> Note: The Identification of the computer can not be changed because: The Certificate Authority Service is installed on this computer

[Here](http://windowsitpro.com/security/how-change-name-certificate-server) I found a solution but didn't work.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If a Windows computer is a certification authority, it can't be renamed and it can't be joined or unjoined to/from a domain. Before renaming the computer or changing its domain membership, you need to remove the Certification Authority role.

Comment: If I remove the role, make the changes and re add the role will I face any problems?

Comment: The service is grayed out and I'm not able to remove it

Comment: Follow the instructions here: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/889250/how-to-decommission-a-windows-enterprise-certification-authority-and-r

Answer (score 0):

Solution:
Go to
->**Server Manager -> Manage(right top) -> Remove Roles and Features -> Server Roles** then uninstall : **Active Directory Certificate Services** and restart VM
Now you should be able to domain rejoin/Unjoin

Comment: What if they actually *need* Certificate Services?

Comment: In that case, Once after the domain is rejoined/Unjoined , you have to add the Certificate services back .

Comment: It's been seven years, but I believe that was established.